# Angular reactive form and ngx-admin problem with error FormGroup isn't a known property of form

Tags: angular, forms, reactive, ngx-admin

I need to use angular ReactiveFormsModule on my custom component with ngx-admin theme but I have the problem when compiling for error: "Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'", on VisualStudioCode no error reported.

I have add "import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';" on my module also on pages.module.ts and app.module.ts without success, I have always that error when compiling.

If I try to add reactive form on Register page of ngx-admin no error when compiling.

Can someone help me to find where I'm wrong?

Comment: You also added these modules to the imports array of your module?

Comment: yes of course!!!!

Comment: can you provide a stackblizz to reproduce?

Comment: without server side login? the server it's not online.

Comment: you need add `import` and add in the array `imports` (Upon a time, I forgot it and become crazy)

Comment: I have add this: import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

Comment: and this:
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,

Comment: Have same issues here.

Answer (score 1):

this is my app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { CoreModule } from './@core/core.module';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { ThemeModule } from './@theme/theme.module';
import { AuthModule } from './@auth/auth.module';

import {
  NbChatModule,
  NbDatepickerModule,
  NbDialogModule,
  NbMenuModule,
  NbSidebarModule,
  NbToastrModule,
  NbWindowModule,
} from '@nebular/theme';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    AuthModule.forRoot(),
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    NbSidebarModule.forRoot(),
    NbMenuModule.forRoot(),
    NbDatepickerModule.forRoot(),
    NbDialogModule.forRoot(),
    NbWindowModule.forRoot(),
    NbToastrModule.forRoot(),
    NbChatModule.forRoot({
      messageGoogleMapKey: 'AIzaSyA_wNuCzia92MAmdLRzmqitRGvCF7wCZPY',
    }),
    CoreModule.forRoot(),
    ThemeModule.forRoot(),
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  providers: [],
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this is my pages.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { PagesComponent } from './pages.component';
import { DashboardModule } from './dashboard/dashboard.module';
import { PagesRoutingModule } from './pages-routing.module';
import { ThemeModule } from '../@theme/theme.module';
import { MiscellaneousModule } from './miscellaneous/miscellaneous.module';
import { PagesMenu } from './pages-menu';
import { ECommerceModule } from './e-commerce/e-commerce.module';
import { NbMenuModule } from '@nebular/theme';
import { AuthModule } from '../@auth/auth.module';

import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';


const PAGES_COMPONENTS = [
  PagesComponent,
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    PagesRoutingModule,
    ThemeModule,
    DashboardModule,
    ECommerceModule,
    NbMenuModule,
    MiscellaneousModule,
    AuthModule.forRoot(),
  ],
  declarations: [
    ...PAGES_COMPONENTS,
  ],
  providers: [
    PagesMenu,
  ],
})
expo
```

rt class PagesModule {
}